# Problems with Python Executable (3.4.3) and libssl path (?)

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl

I had very old Cent OS Toshiba laptop that was operating industrial equipment built by a previous employee at my company completely die on me.  Dead as a doornail, no way to get it back up.

I'm trying to build a new machine with Ubuntu 16.04.3 as the OS to run the custom software that runs our hardware but it's giving me a fit when trying to run the old python executable.  I've searched high and low and can't figure out what is going on.

I'm almost certain it's a path issue, there were some pretty weird install paths hard coded into the software that I can't even rebuild at this point because the mechanism to do so is lost somewhere in cloud land.  So, I have been symbolic linking my new python installation to where the errors from the program were pointing me to and I have made some progress.

But, I can't get the hash libraries for python to work and I think it's because they can't find the Ubuntu SSL libraries based on some other posts I've been reading.  But I'm not super confident, it may be something else entirely that is going on.

The error messages are as follows:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 240, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 118, in __get_builtin_constructor
    """new(name, data=b'') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 240, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 118, in __get_builtin_constructor
    """new(name, data=b'') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 240, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 118, in __get_builtin_constructor
    """new(name, data=b'') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 240, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 118, in __get_builtin_constructor
    """new(name, data=b'') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 240, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 118, in __get_builtin_constructor
    """new(name, data=b'') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 240, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/hashlib.py", line 118, in __get_builtin_constructor
    """new(name, data=b'') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

Any ideas would be very, very much appreciated as to how to get past this. . . and onto the next roadblock!

Comment: `sudo apt install openssl`?

Comment: I did try that to see if it wasn't installed at all earlier, good point I didn't put this in original post.  Here is the output for running this command:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

Comment: How do you launch *python*? Try: `${PYTHON} -c "import platform;print(platform.architecture())"` (by `${PYTHON}` I meant the path to the python executable) and see what the output is. Then type `dpkg -L libssl1.0.0 | grep crypt`, and that should yield a full path to a *.so* file. If it throws an error, try `ldd $(which openssl) | grep crypt`.